# GraphQL Pagination | The very first request

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, relay

According to the connection based model for pagination using graphQL, I have the following simplified schema.

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type UserConnection {
  totalCount: Int
  pageInfo: PageInfo
  edges: [UserEdge]
}

type UserEdge {
  cursor: String
  node: User
}

type PageInfo {
  lastCursor: Int
  hasNextPage: Boolean
}

type Query {
  users(first: Int, after: String): UserConnection
}
```

Consider the following router on within SPA front-end:

`/users` - once the user hit this page, I'm fetching first 10 records right up from the top of the list and further I'm able to paginate by reusing a cursor that I've retrieved from the first response.

`/user/52` - here I'd like to show up 10 records that should go right from the position of user52.

**Problem** What are the possible ways to retrieve a particular subset of records on the very first request? On this moment I don't have any cursor to construct something similar to

```
  query GetTenUsersAfter52 {
    users(first: 10, after: "????") { # struggling to pass anything as a cursor...
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**What I've already tried(a possible solution)** is that I know that on a back-end the cursor is encoded value of an `_id` of the record in the DB. So, being on `/users/52` I can make an individual request for that particular user, grab the value of `id`, then on the front-end I can compute a cursor and pass it to the back-end in the query above.

But in this case personally, I found a couple of disadvantages:

1. I'm exposing the way of how my cursor is computed to the front-end, which is bad since if I needed to change that procedure I need to change it on front-end and back-end...
2. I don't want to make another query field for an individual user simply because I need its id to pass to the `users` query field.
3. I don't want to make 2 API calls for that as well...

Comment: Are you actually using Relay client-side, or just using the Relay convention in your schema and using a different client (like, for example, Apollo)?

Comment: I'm using Apollo Server package as an API server and Apollo Client on front-end accompanied with ReactJS. More importantly, for me is to get a good grasp of how to resolve gracefully aforementioned use case, that's why I tried to not mention any specific technologies except graphQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of how Relay-style pagination can be limiting. You'll hit a similar scenario with create mutations, where manually adding a created object into the cache ends up screwing up your pagination because you won't have a cursor for the created object.

As long as you're not actually using Relay client-side, one solution is to just abandon using cursors altogether. You can keep your `before` and `after` fields, but instead simply accept the `id` (or `_id` or whatever PK) value instead of a cursor. This is what I ended up doing on a recent project and it simplified things significantly.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about this also, that when I opted in relay connection style pagination id brought some complexity which might be unnecessary for some cases(like mine)...